# Angularjs как реализовать тако функционал в md-select'е?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

У меня есть Angular material - `md-select`, в нем есть атрибут `multiple`.
Получается это комбобокс с возможностью выборка нескольких элементов. Но как мне сделать так, что бы каждая группа `<md-optgroup>` была отдельной в этом комбобоксе, и в каждой такой группе можно было выбрать только один элемент одновременно? То есть когда пользователь выбрал один пункт, на нем загорелся чекбокс, и когда он в той же группе выбирает второй пункт, то нужно что бы предыдущий (все остальные пункты группы) автоматом деселектились.

Возможно ли как-то реализовать такой функционал этого ангулар-контролла?

Answer (score 0):

Я честно говоря не работал с Angular Material, но решение мне видится таким (предполагаю, что можно в `md-select` можно разбить на группы)

1) У нас есть коллекция и у нас есть способ разбить её на группы, что мы и делаем и сохраняем её в отдельную сущность (или не сохраняем)

2) На `md-select` вешаем событие `ng-change` или `ng-click` на `option`

3) В обработчике события мы имеем модель и справочник. В обработчике Вы можете как раз выстроить свою логику.

Comment: Ну на C#, на ком я раньше кодил я бы мог сделать типа: Получить в событии `sender` и уже через доступ к самому меню я бы сделал анселект для всех пунктов кроме пункта `sender`. А тут в этом Angular Material я могу что-то подобное сделать?

Comment: Надо смотреть возможности ``md-select``. Но по сути да, надо найти аналогичное событие.